# A great rdp client

Tags: raspbian, remote, windows, rdp

Is there an RDP client for Raspbian OS or smilar that has the fo llowing features:

Dual full screen.
Can share local resources like drives.
Remote audio.
Can be free or paid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two options have been confirmed to work on the RPi: [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/) and [freerdp](http://www.freerdp.com/). These should both work on Raspbian, from within xwin (use startx to get there). You can install either from the terminal prompt using default installer (aptitude).

Install rdesktop with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install rdesktop
```

Run like this:

```
rdesktop <hostname/ip_address_of_Windows_machine>
```

Install freerdp with this command

```
sudo apt-get install freerdp
```

Run like this:

```
xfreerdp <hostname/ip_address_of_Windows_machine>
```

There are more details and a discussion about this subject here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=5814

Comment: Thanks. I found freerdp yesterday.  Think I will go with that